# How to setup my-sql db for unit test in grails 3

Tags: grails, grails3.2.0

I have used following code in application.yml

```
environments:
  test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:mysql://<<IP>>/unit_test_db
            username: ****
            password: ****
```

still grails use in-memory db for unit test.

Answer (score 1):

That may be because your test is running in the development environment.  One thing that can cause that is if you are running tests directly from an IDE in such a way that `grails.env` is not set to `test`.  If you run your tests using Gradle, that happens automatically.  I discuss this around the 36:00 mark of the video at https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/webinar-recording-why-intellij-idea-is-the-premier-ide-for-grails-3/.  If you are using IntelliJ that may be helpful.  Another way to address the issue is to configure the IDE to delegate test running to Gradle.  If you are using a different IDE, the same idea would apply but the details of how to address the issue will depend on what IDE you are using.

If you are seeing the same problem when running from Gradle, then something may be misconfigured in your project and the details of that may be tricky to identify without knowing more about the project.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jeff.   
I'm run using /gradlew test/ and /grails test-app/ command.
I have logged env and db url. Please find as below. still grails use in-memory db.    

2019-07-08 23:03:51.687[INFO] com.ecw.functional.FunctionalSpecsController - ****ENV :test****
2019-07-08 23:03:52.000[INFO] com.ecw.functional.FunctionalSpecsController - ***DB URL :jdbc:mysql://<IP>/unit_test_db****

Comment: @KapilThakkar that looks like the environment is being set correctly.  There are any number of things that might be in the app which could cause the behavior you are describing.  If you can share a sample app which demonstrates the issue, it would be trivial to troubleshoot.